# Good video tutorial on spring security 3.0

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I know that there are many "similar" questions asked in this forum , However there hasnt been any that is specific to what I am asking. Are there any good video tutorials on Spring Security that would start from fundamentals of Spring Security 3.0. Other Docs that are useful are
1. [simple-spring-security-webapp](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-security-webapp.html)
2.[spring-security-mvc-integration](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html)

However I not able to get a good video tutorial that explains spring security.

thanks
Nohsib

Answer (score 2):

I like these ones:

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Spring-Security-3 (january 2011, you need flash player in order to see it)

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Spring-Security-3-1 (december 2011)